# Where do recently played with people show up?

Tags: diablo-iii

Where do I see who my character has recently played with?

I want to know in case I get hacked. Where does that show up?

Comment: Have you checked your friend list?

Answer (score 4):

You can see the people you last played with in the Social menu (which is the friend list).

It will show people you played with that are not in your friend list in a separate group called "Recent players".

Comment: The social menu can be opened by pressing O, or from its small icon in the lower right of the screen.